# SpriteKit view in nativescript

Tags: ios, typescript, sprite-kit, nativescript

Is it possible to show a screen with a Nativescript
I searched the Internet for very little information.
Found the code.

```
const GameViewController = (UIViewController as any).extend(
{
    get willPopCb() { return this._willPopCb; },
    set willPopCb(x) { this._willPopCb = x; },
    viewDidLoad: function(){
        UIViewController.prototype.viewDidLoad.apply(this, arguments);

        this.view = SKView.alloc().initWithFrame(this.view.bounds);
        if(this.view instanceof SKView){
            const scene = BattlefieldScene.alloc().initWithSize(
                this.view.bounds.size
            );
            scene.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.alloc().initWithRedGreenBlueAlpha(0,1,0,1);

            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill;

            this.view.presentScene(scene);
            this.view.showsPhysics = false;
            this.view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true;
            this.view.showsFPS = true;
            this.view.showsNodeCount = true;
        }
    },
    willMoveToParentViewController: function(parent: UIViewController|null){
        if(parent === null){
            if(this.willPopCb){
                this.willPopCb();
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    name: "GameViewController",
    protocols: [],
    exposedMethods: {}
}
```

);

Now, I can not understand how to display this controller

Thank you in advance

Comment: Heya, this is my code – [source](https://github.com/shirakaba/nativescript-grimoire/blob/master/SpriteKit%20game/README.md). You'll see that I also provide a `getUIViewController()` function. Get a reference to a NativeScript `View` element (let's say `view`) and call that function on `view.ios`. Manoj's method will work too, if you're happy with simply using the root view controller.

Comment: Thank you for the code)
I don't understand what a variable design is? If it's not difficult for you, can you tell us in more detail?

Comment: the variable named `design` is one that I exposed as a convenience in my open-source [NS:IDE](https://github.com/shirakaba/nside) app. It's just a normal NativeScript `View` element; you can use any NativeScript `View` you like, as I've said.

Comment: Tell me please, is it possible to bring any element on top of this view?

Comment: It is possible; but I must leave the research to you, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
import * as utils from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils";

const gameViewController = GameViewController.alloc().init();
const app = utils.ios.getter(UIApplication, UIApplication.sharedApplication);
app.keyWindow.rootViewController.presentViewControllerAnimatedCompletion(gameViewController, true, null);
```

Comment: app.keyWindow is null ((

Comment: When exactly you are accessing the key window?

Comment: Could you be more specific please?

Comment: I'm trying to create a component in Angular. That would pull it view.